# How to bind DataTemplate on PhoneApplicationPage.Resources when page is already bound to another class?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have edited the question to include more info based on the feedback.

In my SettingsPage.xaml I have

```
   <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lpkCountry" 
ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource lpkItemTemplate}}" 
FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource lpkFullItemTemplate}}" 
Header="your country" CacheMode="BitmapCache" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280" Height="82" />
```

I am trying to bind the ListPicker DataTemplate to the following XAML placed in the App.xaml page

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="lpkItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="lpkFullItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Margin="16 0 0 0" Text="{Binding Country}" />
    </DataTemplate>
 </Application.Resources>
```

The SettingsPage.xaml.cs defined Country as public static string array:

```
namespace myspace
{
    public partial class SettingsPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public static String[] Country = {
                            "Afghanistan",
                            "Åland Islands",
                            "Albania",
                            "Algeria",
                            "American Samoa",
                            "Andorra",
                            "Angola"}
                            ......;
```

Also on the SettingsPage.xaml.cs I have defined the datacontext to another object.

```
    public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         this.lpkCountry.SelectionChanged += new  SelectionChangedEventHandler(lpkCountry_SelectionChanged);
        this.lpkCountry.ItemsSource = Country;
        settings = new AppSettings();
        this.DataContext = settings;
    }
```

But on runtime when I go to SettingsPage I get many errors of this kind

System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Country' property not found on 'Afghanistan' 'System.String' (HashCode=-2039466552). BindingExpression: Path='Country' DataItem='Afghanistan' (HashCode=-2039466552); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..

I understand that there's conflict between target element and target property, so how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious mistake is `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`. This means you try to bind to the very same object, like TextBox or ListPicker. Runtime is absolutely right in this case: `'lpkItemTemplate' property not found on 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ListPicker'`

I guess something like `Source={StaticResource lpkItemTemplate}` would help, if you define your data template somewhere in App.xaml, in `<Application.Resources>` section.

**EDIT:** after you added more code. Your items source is an array of strings, so in data template you should use the following binding:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem now is that the text property of the listpicker is bound to the class's public property which is defined via code. i.e: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" />`. If I place the data template in App.xaml, what is the correct path to use?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you place the data template, since it's only applied during the run time. You should keep the same path, `<TextBlock Text={Binding Country} />`

Comment: The reason I asked is that because I get the error for all the country list such as  `System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Country' property not found on 'Zimbabwe' 'System.String' (HashCode=993922277). BindingExpression: Path='Country' DataItem='Zimbabwe' (HashCode=993922277); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..`

Comment: Your error says that system cannot find `Country` property on type `string`, which is not a surprise, really. It seems that you have something wrong in a binding arrangements. If string ("Zimbabwe") is the object on which runtime tries to search the property, you should be able to write binding expression like this: `<TextBlock Text={Binding} />`. Try and see if it works. And in general, it's hard to fix the bindings without seeing all the code, so if you're still failing to achieve what you want, post more code.

Comment: I've edited my question. I understand what it cannot find and that's not surprising. That's why I am asking how to properly find it

Comment: Great! If it worked for you, please consider marking this question as answered.